# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I have been working on angular and i wanted to use firebase for back end. I install angular fire following this instruction https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md
here is my package.json

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
```

I am facing this problem. Can anyone help me with this?

```
ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts(4,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.  node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts(17,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
```

Comment: See also [angularfire2#1387](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387) and [firebase-js-sdk#388](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/388)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change your firebase version back to `4.8.0`. There was an issue in type definitions and its no longer work after updating from 4.8.0 to 4.8.1.

So change the version in the `package.json` file. remove the `^`

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "4.8.0",
```

Now execute the `npm install` command. This will install the `4.8.0` version

For further info refer [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/387#issuecomment-352854981) and [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/388).

Comment: @Solomon no problem :)

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka How do I change the version?

Comment: @Ivantha in package json change the version and run `npm install`

Comment: Hi, this solution doesn't work for me. If I do ionic serve after following those steps it keep saying me that he cannot find the modules.

Comment: I do find that this stated error goes away when moving back to `4.8.0` but for me it introduces a ton of "implicity any" errors (which I guess I could ignore) but also some other less understood errors.

Answer (score 13):

There's a problem with the newest npm firebase package (v4.8.1).

To fix this problem, in your terminal.
Type

```
npm uninstall --save firebase
```

Now, open your `package.json` file.
There, you will find:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
```

Below this line, add a this line (Note, here is no **Caret**(^) symbol):

```
"firebase": "4.8.0",
```

After saving, hit `npm install`. Now, your application will work fine and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

if problem persists ,
my shortcut is that just open providers/firebase/firebase.ts ,
just copy all content and paste it again on it.. 
it will work fine with firebase database if no error on other program.

if anyone know permanent solution for this... share it..

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who came to this question from Google or elsewhere, `AngularFire2 RC.6` has been released with full support for the latest firebase SDK. At the time of writing this the Firebase JavaScript SDK is at `v4.8.2`, or `v4.9.0`. The solution provided in this question was correct for that time. If this question were to be asked today, the answer should be to upgrade `Angularfire2` to the latest along with `Firebase v4.8.1` or higher.

If your build runs without any problems, then you are probably on Windows. I am finding that I am not able to build on a Mac or Linux machine ATM. I will be posting a question about that shortly.

Hope this helps somebody!