# Firebase client library failing typings

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting the latest Firebase npm module (`4.8.1`). I am using the commonjs module system with webpack bundling. In order to ensure I'm getting the typings I need I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies: {
  "firebase": "^4.8.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@firebase/app": "^0.1.5",
  "@firebase/app-types": "^0.1.0",
  "@firebase/auth": "^0.3.1",
  "@firebase/auth-types": "^0.1.0",
  "@firebase/database": "^0.1.6",
  "@firebase/database-types": "0.1.0",
}
```

When I transpile with `tsc` I get the following errors:

> node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts(4,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
>
> node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts(17,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.

I find this VERY odd for several reasons:

1. I am using **CommonJS** module system not **ESM**
2. I have assumed that the `@firebase/data-types` is there to provide *typings* rather than implementation code. That's why I have it listed as as **devDependency** instead of **dependency**
3. Even if I switch all the `@firebase/*` to "dependencies" it still gives same error
4. I did see other people post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927038/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private) that Firebase 4.8.1 has an error in it and that rolling back to 4.8.0 might fix the problem ... but from what I can see 4.8.0 has all sort of "implicit any" errors (which maybe I could justify turning off) but also lots of other deprecations in the API that is exported. Simply put, it appears to me that 4.8.1 is much better as typings reference.

Answer (score 1):

With the following `tsconfig.json`it works fine for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  }
}
```

In `src/index.ts` I just import like this:

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>',
  messagingSenderId: '<your-sender-id>'
});
```

Before I modified my `tsconfig.json` I had similar issue with:

```
{
...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "firebase": "^4.8.1"
  }
}
```

I hope that helps!